# Compute $\sum_{k=0}^{1006}\binom{2013}{2k}$ using mathematical induction.

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

> $$
> \mbox{Compute}\quad\sum_{k=0}^{1006}{2013 \choose 2k}
> $$

Hi, I know that I have to use induction but I am kinda stuck here.

any tips or suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Comment: How do you "know" that you have to use induction? There is nothing to induct! You can just plug this into a calculator if you want.

Comment: Of course, if you wanted to generalize this computation to, let's say, the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}$$
**then** you could try induction on $n$.

Comment: ^^ ill try that. I can only set it up and i am not sure what to do

Comment: okay so I have been putting some small numbers to n. So when n=2, it becomes 3. when n=4, it becomes 8. when n=6, it becomes 32. what do i do now?

Comment: @Dafty Conjecture a general form and prove it.

Comment: We don't compute with 'Induction'. We prove some statement with 'Induction'. The question must be "Use 'Induction' to prove that $\displaystyle{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}{n \choose 2k} = 2^{n - 1}}$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k$$
If you let $x=-1$, then you have: 
$$
0=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}-...\pm \binom{n}{n}
$$Move the binomials with an odd $k$ to the left, to obtain the identity: 
$$
\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{5}+...=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+...
$$Call the sum on the right $O_n$ (for odds :-)) and the one on the left $E_n$. By above you have that $O_n=E_n$.

What do you know about $O_n+E_n$? (this is just the summation of all the binomial coefficients). You would now have a $2$ by $2$ system of equations and can find exactly what $E_n$ is.

Added: The first identity I have also works to find out what $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$ is:

$$
2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}1^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}
$$

Comment: hey thank you for the tip. I am getting what you wrote. but I am not sure how to apply it... :/

Comment: Do you know what $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+...+\binom{n}{n}$ equals to?

Comment: no. unfortunately I don't know. could you remind me?

Comment: I will walk you through it :D, more fun if you get it. What does $\binom{n}{k}$ represent combinatorically?

Comment: n choose k. n!/{(n-k)!k!}

Comment: Ok, I have a question. If you want to find out what $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+...+\binom{n}{n}$, what would you let $x$ be in the first equation I have above?

Comment: My hint depends on the fact that $2013$ is odd, yours does not.  But I think mine is simpler.  Hope OP can get there....

Comment: Look at the RHS of the equation. It reads $\sum \binom{n}{k}x^k$ and you want $\sum \binom{n}{k}$. What is $x$?

Comment: @DanielMontealegre isn't x = 0?

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}x^k=\binom{n}{k}$. Find $x$.

Comment: @DanielMontealegre x=1

Comment: @RossMillikan This works in the even and odd case for $n$. I just didn't bother writing the last terms on the sums on my last equation because they will involve floor functions and might confuse the OP

Comment: @Dafty, ok what happens if you plug in $x=1$ in the first equation?

Comment: @DanielMontealegre the first equation so 1^k is just 1.

Comment: @Dafty Check what I added.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10671/discussion-between-daniel-montealegre-and-dafty)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  ${n \choose r}={n \choose n-r}$

Comment: yeah I know that before. so if i expand this, the 2st term and like (n-1)th term will cancel out??

Comment: All the terms are positive, so nothing will cancel.  But if you try to evaluate a different sum the terms will match one by one.

Comment: oh right. I was thinking of other inductions. okay i'll think about what you said for a bit... ty!

Comment: @Dafty If $n$ is an odd number, then when $r = 2k$ runs through all even number $\le n$, $n - r$ runs through all odd numbers $\le n$. So twice of your sum is equal to...

Comment: @RossMillikan hey I really don't know how to apply that for my question. could you give me some more?

Comment: You are adding up the even combinations of $2013$.  My point is you can also add up the odd ones.  What do you get?

Comment: @RossMillikan it'd be as same as adding up the even combinations.

Comment: That is correct.  So it you add up *all* the combinations what do you get?  My hint shows that the sum of the odds is the same as the sum of the evens (assuming the universe is odd-see the other answer for why that doesn't matter)

Comment: @RossMillikan okay isn't adding up all the combinations like adding all the rows in Pascal's triangle? but here i only need to add even ones. I don't know how... i forgot.

Comment: Yes, you are adding up all the odd entries of that row in Pascal's triangle.  If the sum of the evens equals the sum of the odds, the sum of the evens is half the sum of all of them.  Do you know what the sum all the entries of row 2013 is?  This is a general result, though my hint only does odd rows.  The sum of the evens equals the sum of the odds for even rows as well.

Answer (score 1):

To generalize the case for $ n $

$ \sum \limits_{k=0}^\frac{n}{2} {n \choose 2k}  = {n \choose 0} + {n \choose 2}   + ....  {n \choose n-2} + {n \choose n}   $

So, as $ {n \choose k} + {n \choose k+1} = {n+1 \choose k+1} $ (elemental identity), you can decompose the above formula as

$ \sum \limits_{k=0}^\frac{n}{2} {n \choose 2k}  = {n-1 \choose 0} + [{n-1 \choose 1}   + {n-1 \choose 2}] + [{n-1 \choose 3} + {n-1 \choose 4}] + .... [{n-1 \choose n-3} + {n-1 \choose n-2}] + {n-1 \choose n-1}  $

You can see that the previous formula represents the sum of the elements in the (n-1) row of Pascal's triangle, so if you take a look at the triangle, you can conjecture that the sum of the row $n$ is represented by $2^n$ (by induction), hence

$ \sum \limits_{k=0}^\frac{n}{2} {n \choose 2k}  = {n \choose 0} + {n \choose 2}   + ....  {n \choose n-2} + {n \choose n}  = 2^{(n-1)} $